# Applescript and 'notes': Open note in new window

Tags: applescript

In 'Notes' it is possible to open a certain note in a new window (and without the note-overview at the left side visible) by double clicking on it in the list of notes.

There must be a way to do that via applescript... I couldn't find anything referring to that problem, even after a pretty long research.

Is there anybody who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using plain vanilla **AppleScript** there is not a programmatic way other then to use **UI Scripting**. Note that this will also require giving e.g. **Script Editor**, or whichever app is running the **AppleScript** *code*, [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) for this to work properly.

You need to tell **Notes** to `show` the `note` by `name` or `id` and then use **System Events** to *click* the **Float Selected Note** *menu item* on the **Window** *menu* of **Notes**.

```
tell application "Notes"
    show note "Foobar"
    activate
end tell

delay 0.5

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Notes" to ¬
        click menu item "Float Selected Note" of ¬
            menu 1 of ¬
            menu bar item "Window" of ¬
            menu bar 1
```

**Note:** Change `Foobar` to the `name` of the `note` you want to open in a separate window or use its `id`, e.g.:

```
note id "x-coredata://C48EA527-911C-49D0-950F-A15229B7D58F/ICNote/p55"
```

You can also tell **Notes** to `show` a `note` by *number* and also include the `name` of an `account` as well as the `name` of a `folder` (if applicable), e.g.:

```
tell application "Notes"
    tell account "Name"
        tell folder "Name"
            show note 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

**Note:** Replace `Name` with the actual name of the *object*. Change the *number* of the `note` as needed.

Then use the **System Events** *command* as shown further above to click the target *menu item*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>